# Spring - @Repository annotation in service class

Tags: java, spring

What is the point of putting **@Repository** in service class `CustomerServiceImpl` and is it a good practice in [this](https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa) example, my understanding it is not needed for any interfaces that extend `JpaRepository` and exception translation already included. As far as I understand @Repository "should" be on repository class?

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  @Autowired
  private CustomerRepository repository;
  ...
}



@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {}
```

Comment: Just quote from your given link _The class is annotated with @Repository to enable exception translation from JPA exceptions to Spring’s DataAccessException hierarchy._ and in article refactored the code in next portion to describe details of repository model

Comment: but isn't this already covered in CustomerRepository

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the @Repository annotation may not be absolutely necessary in the given example for the CustomerServiceImpl class.

However, the use of @Repository annotation optimizes the 'search' and 'List all' operations by implementing the 'Domain Driven Design' pattern.

Example:  The underlying repository can be a Relational database / No-sql database /  a CSV file. Use of @Repository will hide the implementation complexity from 'Search' and 'List all' operations in this case.